# Sqlite.swift missing label "where"

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I am using the sqlite.swift library found [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#filtering-rows)

Below is the code I am using to filter results:

```
.filter(mdm[assetTag] != "ipad" && location == facility && [tagArray].contains(appversion))
```

I am getting the following error for the .contains portion:

> Missing argument label 'where' in call.

I am following the readme and there shouldn't need to be a where clause added within the .contains section of the filter.

**Update:**

Declaration of the arrays are as follows:

```
var tagarray = [String]()

let appversion = Expression<String>("appversion")
```

Comment: Please post `tagArray` and `appversion`'s declaration. I know what the problem is but need the values to provide the exact answer

Comment: Added declaration to the original question.

Comment: `tagArray.contains(appversion)` instead?

Comment: @Larme yep that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode thinks you are using Swift's `contains(where:)` instead of `where(_:)` defined by the library.

[image]

Your variable `appversion` needs to be of type `Expression<String>`.

```
let appversion = Expression<String>("appversion")
let tags = ["1.0","2.0.0","3.0"]

someTable.filter(tags.contains(appversion))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I just posted all the `contains` functions available. If it's of type Expression, then where doesn't even apply

Comment: If I change the filter and hard code values in like you did with "1", "2" etc then the error goes away but when I use tagArray I get the error.

Comment: Seems all I need to do was remove the [] around the array to this:  .filter(mdm[assetTag] != "ipad" && location == facility && tagArray.contains(appversion))

Comment: Ohhh right. Missed that. You were using an Array of Arrays.